# Status is GATT_FAILURE in onConnectionStateChange after many reconnections

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt

I'm connecting to ble device by:

```
 mBluetoothGatt = device.connectGatt(this.context, false, mGattCallback);
```

and than

```
 mBluetoothGatt.disconnect();
```

but if I'm doing it quickly then I receive `status=BluetoothGatt.GATT_FAILURE` in `onConnectionStateChange` of `mGattCallback`

and then I can't connect to GATT again, even if turn off/turn on Bluetooth.

Only Force Stop of the app can solve the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed by adding `mBluetoothGatt.close();` when state is `STATE_DISCONNECTED`

```
private final BluetoothGattCallback mGattCallback =
            new BluetoothGattCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status,int newState) {
                    String intentAction;

                    if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {

                    } else if (status==133&&newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
                        mBluetoothGatt.close();
                    }else if (status==BluetoothGatt.GATT_FAILURE&&newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED){

                    } else if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
                        mBluetoothGatt.close();
                    }
                }
```